# Why FB.getLoginStatus doesn't work in IE7?

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-7

I am using `FB.getLoginStatus` for an application in Facebook. This works fine in all the browsers, including IE8. But it doesn't work for IE7. My code is:

```js
       FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {              
           if (response.session) {
              alert("logout");
            }
            else{
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    login();
                });
              alert("login");
            }
        });
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I set the channelUrl  : 'example.com/facebook/' in the FB.init and it worked!

Comment: +1 channelUrl worked for me too!  Was pulling my hair out on this one.  thanks

Comment: Just a note, I also see the same problem in IE8. The answer posted below resolves the issue in both IE7 and IE8 for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.init/, the proper solution is to create a file on your web server (for instance `channel.html`) containing just:

```html
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

And then specifying the absolute URL to your channel.html in your init options:

```html
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script>
   FB.init({
     appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
     channelUrl  : 'http://example.com/channel.html'  // custom channel
   });
 </script>
```

For convenience in deployment, I use the following to calculate my channelUrl.

```js
 var curLoc = window.location;
 curLoc.protocol + "//" + curLoc.hostname + ":" + curLoc.port + "/channel.html"
```

Comment: An invalid channel file URL will cause this to fail in IE7, while other browsers will still work fine, including IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this API (FB.getLoginStatus) is not working anymore on IE7 browsers.

Take a look here:
[getLoginStatus not Fired on IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681133/getloginstatus-not-fired-on-ie7)

If you try to run the code in the following page on IE7 it's not working:
http://www.fbrell.com/auth/login-and-logout

It seems the "channelUrl" fix is not working anymore and the IE7 support for the Facebook Javascript SDK is compromised.