# IE8 Support - Javascript causes page load to hang. Where to start

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, dotnetnuke

I recently took my first stab at creating a responsive, mobile friendly, web site. I got everything looking and working honkey dory for all the modern browsers. However, I recently ran my first test in a while on IE8.

Upon IE Developer Tools in IE8, the page produces a host a javascript and various errors. These errors cause the page produce multiple error pop-ups, and also cause it to hang indefinitely on the "connecting..." message.

It might be a long road ahead troubleshooting these IE8 issues, but I'm ready to dig my feet in deep and figure it out. The only problem is, I have no idea where to start. I can see the errors reference a few things in IE Developer Tools, but as of yet I have not identified what is even causing the errors.

I guess my question is: would someone mind taking a quick gander at my site to view these issues? If you know of any great tools for debugging issues such as these, please share! Any other suggestions would also be welcome!

The site is built on ASP.NET, DotNetNuke CMS.

www.yandasmusic.com

Here is the pop-up error produced twice in IE8 on page load:
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Here is a few of the errors produced in the IE8 Script Debug Console. It seems to reproduce these same set of errors over and over:

- Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
- FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().
- FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem
- Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or
- Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Can you update with an error or two?

Comment: Yep no problem. Added the error list. It would seem that although the console is showing over 40 errors, they are all duplicates of the above set.

Comment: I think you may have inadvertantly asked a duplicate question.  Check out this answer, and see if it helps...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679610/why-fb-getloginstatus-doesnt-work-in-ie7

Comment: The beginning of the file looks messy, please [validate](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) your HTML, IE10 complained about double `HTML` tag...

Comment: @Teemu Cleaned. Sorry about that, was playing yesterday and forgot to save changes.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I recognized the FB.getLoginStatus as the page trying to connect to facebook for some reason. I know that DNN has the option to enable facebook authentication, but to my knowledge I have never even attempted to enable this. There are a few facebook share buttons, so I tried removing them and re-testing. The error still remained.